# 70s-80s: Desolate earth; experiment gone wrong

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for an old sci-fi movie (probably 1980's or before).

The movie was about a small subset of the human population suddenly being left on Earth. There was some calamity where the majority of the population was just suddenly absent. The bulk of the movie I think was about the main character exploring the empty world and eventually trying to find out what happened and if it could be reversed.

Some scenes I remember:

- The main character moved/squatted in a mansion for months (maybe years) with scenes of him going a little mad from loneliness. I think at some point someone else may have turned up to which he was shocked.
- It turns out that the only people occupying the Earth are those who died/were killed during some kind of physics experiment.
- The main character was drowned by someone else in a river at the time of the experiment
- For the conclusion, a large lorry was used to drive into a building which housed the experiment

I don't remember the outcome or much else of the movie, but would be interested in learning what the movie was as I have thought of it on and off for decades...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like [*The Quiet Earth*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089869/) (1985).

Quoting the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quiet_Earth_(film)#Plot):

> Zac Hobson is a scientist employed by Delenco, part of a United States-led international consortium working on "Project Flashlight" – an experiment to create a wireless global energy grid to power military equipment. He awakens abruptly; when he turns on his radio, he is unable to receive any transmissions. He drives into the city, which he finds deserted. Investigating a fire, he discovers the burning wreckage of a passenger jet, but there are no bodies, only empty seats. **Every living animal and human appears to have vanished between the ticks of a clock.**
>
> [...]
> After a week of trying to contact another human being, **Zac moves into a mansion. His mental state begins to deteriorate. He puts on a woman's nightgown and alternates between exhilaration and despair**. He assembles cardboard cutouts of famous people (including Adolf Hitler, Elizabeth II, and Pope John Paul II), plays a loud fanfare and cheers from large speakers, and addresses the cutouts from a balcony. He declares himself "President of this Quiet Earth", then goes on a destructive rampage after the power blacks out. He bursts into a church, shoots a statue of Jesus off a crucifix, and announces that he is God. After accidentally crushing an empty pram with an enormous earthmover, he puts the barrel of a shotgun into his mouth, but desists. This event serves to break his insanity.
>
> Zac settles into a more normal routine. **One morning, a young woman named Joanne appears**. Zac is attracted to her, and after a few days they have sex. They find a third survivor, a Māori man named Api. **The three determine why they survived: at the instant of The Effect, they were all at the moment of death: Api was being drowned** during a fight, Joanne was electrocuted by a faulty hairdryer, and Zac had overdosed on pills in a suicide attempt. He had realized the experiment posed serious dangers and was guilt-ridden for not speaking out. The discovery of his body, with his lab ID and tape recorder nearby, would have the consequence of exposing Project Flashlight and ending the experiment before it was too late.
>
> [...]
> While Zac is gone, Joanne and Api have sex. Afterward, Api tells Joanne that he will sacrifice himself by driving the truck; he doubts that Zac's device will be capable of controlling the vehicle. They then hear the truck. Zac has not returned to town and **drives the truck onto the gas-bomb-weakened roof of the laboratory**, which caves in. Just as the Second Effect occurs, he triggers the explosives.

Comment: Thanks! will have to rewatch it now.

Comment: I thought the ending was Very Spooky.